# Suppose $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}$. Prove by contradiction that if $a^{2}+b^{2}=c^{2}$, then $a$ or $b$ is even.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, modular-arithmetic

I am going through the Book of Proof, by Richard Hammack, and in the chapter on Proof by Contradiction, I came across the following exercise:

Suppose $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}$. Prove by contradiction that if $a^{2}+b^{2}=c^{2}$, then $a$ or $b$ is even.

My proof was the following:

For the sake of contradiction, suppose it is not the case that $a$ or $b$ are even. By De Morgan's Law, that means that $a$ and $b$ are odd.

We proved in exercise 7 that the quadratics residue modulo $4$ is either $0$ or $1$. Thus, $c^{2}\equiv 0(\textrm{mod }4)$ or $c^{2}\equiv 1(\textrm{mod }4)$. Lets look into both cases separately:

Case 1: If $c^{2}\equiv 0(\textrm{mod }4)$, it follows that $4\mid c^{2}$, that is, there is an integer $k_1$ such that $c^{2}=4k_1$. Hence, $4k_1=a^{2}+b^{2}$, and $a^{2}=4k_1-b^{2}$, but since $b$ is odd, there is an integer $m_1$ such that $b=2m+1$, and $a^{2}=4k_1-(2m+1)^{2}=4(k_1-m^{2}-m)-1=4(k_1-m^{2}-m-1)+3$, which means  $a^{2}\equiv 3(\textrm{mod }4)$ which contradicts the fact that the quadratics residue modulo $4$ is either $0$ or $1$.

Case 2: If $c^{2}\equiv 1(\textrm{mod }4)$, it follows that $4\mid c^{2}-1$, that is, there is an integer $k_2$ such that $c^{2}-1=4k_2$. Hence, $4k_2=a^{2}+b^{2}+1$, and $a^{2}=4k_2-b^{2}-1$, but since $b$ is odd, there is an integer $m$ such that $b=2m+1$, and $a^{2}=4k_2-(2m+1)^{2}-1=4(k_2-m^{2}-m)-2=4(k_2-m^{2}-m-1)+2$, which means  $a^{2}\equiv 2(\textrm{mod }4)$ which contradicts the fact that the quadratics residue modulo $4$ is either $0$ or $1$.

In either case, we arrived at a contradiction, so it is not the case that $a$ and $b$ are odd. Therefore, $a$ is even or $b$ is even. That concludes the proof. $\blacksquare$

The question is even numbered, so it does not have a solution at the end of the book, so I needed someone to check if it is correct and maybe give me some advice to improve my proof writting skills. Thanks

Comment: What’s exercise 7?

Comment: This seems correct, but it is more traditional to have phrased "*suppose $a$ and $b$ are odd.  Let $a=2k+1$ and $b=2\ell + 1$ and so $a^2=4k^2+4k+1$ and $b^2 = 4\ell^2+4\ell+1$.  It follows that $a^2+b^2\equiv 2\pmod{4}$*" from which you can cite your exercise 7 and finish there.  This takes many fewer lines and is easier to follow.

Comment: @insipidintegrator exercise 7 is obviously the exercise to prove that the quadratic residues modulo 4 are either 0 or 1.  The OP already said as much... It is perfectly acceptable in a course to refer to results already proven in the course or exercises so they don't have to prove them again every single time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very very short solution:

a and b are odd so $$a^2\equiv b^2\equiv 1\bmod 4$$ so $$a^2+b^2=c^2\equiv 1+1\equiv 2\bmod 4$$ which is not possible as squares can only be $\equiv 0,1\bmod 4.$ Contradiction.

Comment: This is the best way, I guess. But at this point in the book, all we know about congruence modulo n is the definition, so I would have to prove that if $x\equiv 1\textrm{mod }4$ and $y\equiv 1\textrm{mod }4$, then $x+y\equiv 2\textrm{mod }4$.

Comment: What’s the definition you know?

Comment: If the definition is “if $x\equiv n\bmod m$ then $m|(x-n)$”, then it’s easy to prove. $4|(x-1)$ and $4|(y-1)$ so $4| ((x-1)+ (y-1))$ which implies $4|((x+y)-2)$ so $x+y\equiv 2\bmod 4$ .

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).